# Must I have licensing?

Tags: android

In android developer console, there is a point that licensing .What should i do? I done yes or no.If I click no what will be bad for me ? 
this :

```
Copy ProtectionOff (Application can be copied from the device)On (Helps prevent copying of this application from the device. Increases the amount of memory on the phone required to install the application.)
The copy protection feature will be deprecated soon, please use licensing service instead.
```

Comment: It asks you if you want to use some lame DRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as it says although copy protection has in fact been deprecated already so you would wisely choose the "off" option. In the android market you will have only the "off" option.

Comment: ı select off? it does not problem?

Comment: No, it will for sure cause less problems than the "On" option. No DRM = less problems as a rule of thumbs.